# cmake rpath not loading all libraries

Tags: cmake, shared-libraries, ld

I am writing a program where the build is done using cmake. In the cmake file I setup the rpath to point to the directories of the shared libraries I use. I also have some other libraries such as vtk installed in $HOME/.local/vtk-v8.2.0/lib

```
if( ${APPLE} )
    set(CMAKE_MACOSX_RPATH ON)
endif()

SET(CMAKE_SKIP_BUILD_RPATH  FALSE)
SET(CMAKE_BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH FALSE)

SET(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib")

SET(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH_USE_LINK_PATH TRUE)

LIST(FIND CMAKE_PLATFORM_IMPLICIT_LINK_DIRECTORIES "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib" isSystemDir)
IF("${isSystemDir}" STREQUAL "-1")
    SET(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/${libDir}")
ENDIF("${isSystemDir}" STREQUAL "-1")
```

The rpath is correctly set

```
$ readelf -d ./myExec.so | rg RUNPATH  
$    0x000000000000001d (RUNPATH)            Library runpath: [/home/ashkan/myExec/install/lib:/home/ashkan/.local/vtk-v8.2.0/lib]
```

but when I check my executable it does not find all the shared libraries.

```
$ ldd ./myExec | egrep 'vtk'
$         libvtkCommonMath-8.2.so.1 => /home/ashkan/.local/vtk-v8.2.0/lib/libvtkCommonMath-8.2.so.1 (0x00007f2bcf28d000)
          libvtkCommonCore-8.2.so.1 => /home/ashkan/.local/vtk-v8.2.0/lib/libvtkCommonCore-8.2.so.1 (0x00007f2bcee4c000)
          libvtksys-8.2.so.1 => not found
```

Also I have checked and the shared library that says "not found" is actually in the same directory as the others.

Any ideas why this would be the case?

Comment: Have you checked `RUNPATH` of `myExec` executable? What it is printed?

Comment: Yes sorry I put the RUNPATH with the wrong name but it has the path. I corrected it now